# Wix -Custom Action after installation ends

Tags: wix, custom-action

Wix - IS there a way to execute any Custom Action after installer installs app and exit out?
Want to execute Custom Action in async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, read the official WiX tutorial:
http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/well-done